# Minify javascript files with Node JS

Tags: node.js

We are using node js to minify javascript files in one single file. I want to know if there is a way to specify the order of the js files to be minified. Why? because we are using jquery-ui and moment datepicker. These two libraries are using a function that has the same name (datepicker). We are able to manage on the development environment to load first jquery-ui and after moment datepicker because we need the one on the moment datepicker file, so loading the files on this way, everything is good but when we end up on the deploying using Node JS, the jquery-ui comes at the end and overrides the moment datepicker and the datepicker is not working as expected. We are also using require js in our project. Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess the concrete solutions depends on which minifier you use and how you bundle your JS files. In the simplest case, just concat the file in the order you want them to be and then minify.

Comment: I'm using uglify. I guess right now is taking it automatically from the require js load because I'm not specifying any order